# Rotating an oriented surface in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an oriented surface `S` in three dimensions. Let's say that initially the surface is parallel to the x-y-plane with orientation vector `ori = {a,b,0}` and normal vector `n = {0,0,1}`. Now I want to rotate this surface, but by doing so always preserve the orientation with respect to the normal in the original coordinate system. For example, if I want to rotate the surface by `180°` I can do two different things - rotate around the x-axis, or the y-axis (for completeness, I also define a z-axis rotation matrix):

```
ori = {a,b,0};
n = {0,0,1};
Rx = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[α], -Sin[α]}, {0, Sin[α], Cos[α]}};
Ry = {{Cos[β], 0, Sin[β]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[β], 0, Cos[β]}};
Rz = {{Cos[γ], -Sin[γ], 0}, {Sin[γ], Cos[γ], 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
```

The result for the rotation of the normal vector is the same in both cases:

```
Rx.{0, 0, 1} /. α -> π
```

> ```
> {0,0,-1}
> ```

```
Ry.{0, 0, 1} /. β -> π
```

> ```
> {0,0,-1}
> ```

But doing the same thing for the orientation vector obviously gives different results:

```
Rx.{a, b, 0} /. α -> π
```

> ```
> {a,-b,0}
> ```

```
Ry.{a, b, 0} /. β -> π
```

> ```
> {-a,b,0}
> ```

So we see that doing arbitrary rotations of the surface such that the normal ends up pointing in a desired direction may or may not change the orientation of the surface. What I would like to do is define a subset of rotations such that I can rotate the normal to point in any direction in the 3D space (to become parallel to given numerical vectors) while also maintaining the correct orientation of the surface. Is this possible? How should I do this?

Comment: It may be helpful to look up `RotationTransform`.

Comment: Yes, I did that. `RotationTransform` takes the two vectors, finds the angle between them and a corresponding rotation axis and gives back a rotation matrix around this axis by this angle. Unfortunately, rotation matrices generated this way are also not consistent in respect to the surface orientation (some rotations give one orientation, others the other one).